# How to Load data from Google Bucket to Google BigQuery Table?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Scenario need to be catered:

1. User will share sales.csv file in Google Bucket
2. sales.csv file data should be uploaded in the Google BigQuery everytime with the timestamp.

Can someone guide me how to do it with best practices?

Answer (score 1):

**for that you need to follow these steps:-**

> Step 1:- Create a Google Cloud Storage bucket

> Step 2:- Set up Google Cloud Functions

> Step 3:- Write the Cloud Function (You can  write cloud functions  in  any computer language)

```py
    from google.Cloud import storage, bigquery

    def load_sales_data(event, context):
      file = event
      timestamp = str(int(time.time() * 1000))
      table_name = f"sales_{timestamp}"
      bucket_name = file['bucket'] #your bucket name
     file_name = file['name'] #your file name

    bq_client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset = bq_client.dataset('my_dataset')# your  dataset name
    table = dataset.table(table_name) #your table name
    schema = [
        bigquery.SchemaField("id", "INTEGER"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("date", "DATE"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("amount", "FLOAT"),
    ]
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
        skip_leading_rows=1,
        autodetect=True,
        schema=schema,
    )
    uri = f"gs://{bucket_name}/{file_name}"
    load_job = bq_client.load_table_from_uri(uri,table,job_config=job_config)
    load_job.result()

    print(f"Data loaded into {table_name}")
```

Comment: Hi @Parthis, Do I need to create Pub/Sub, Function, or Scheduler ?

Comment: yes, you need  Trigger and Scheduler.

Comment: what should I write in requirement.txt ?